# Limiting and Aliasing fields returned using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have an existing WP database that I am trying utilize to create an API using node and sequelize. I'd like to limit the fields which are returned in the query as WP adds a ton of fields I don't want to display in the API. From what I understood, when I define the model, the fields I used, should be the only ones which are returned. It appears though, that the query created is simply using '*'. Also, the aliasing of the field names, do not seem to be happening either. Below is my model.

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
var Campground = sequelize.define('Campground', {
    ID: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    Name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'post_title'
    },
    Description: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        field: 'post_content'
    }
}, {
    tableName: 'wp_posts',
    timestamps: false,
    defaultScope: {
        where: {
            post_type: 'campgrounds'
        }
    },
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(models) {
            Campground.hasMany(models.Meta, {
                as: 'Park_Info',
                foreignKey: 'post_id'
            })
            Campground.hasOne(models.Locator, {
                foreignKey: 'post_id'
            })
        }
    }
})

return Campground
}
```

Comment: What version are you using? `field` support might only be present in 2.0. As for the fields being selected, the default is always * unless you use the `attributes` option on find/findAll.

Answer (score 0):

@MickHansen's comment was the answer I was looking for. See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#findall

Comment: Link seems to be broken, please verify it